# Filter CollectionView based on multiple criteria

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF application with a search textbox and Listview bindined to ICollectionView. I can filter the ICollectionView based on texbox value, however I am interested to extend the functionality by passing multiple values separated by comma and apply multiple Filtering to the collection.

```
 var filterStrings= TextBoxValue.Split(',');

 MyCollectionView.Filter = m => 
     (((MyObject)m).myProperty.ToLower().ContainsAll(filterStrings)
```

where ContainsAll is Extension

```
 public static bool ContainsAll(this string source, params string[] values)
 {
      return values.All(x => source.Contains(x));
 }
```

The filter doesn't include multiple results, any idea why ? Thank you

## EDIT

The collection has simple string values (Bob,Bin,Grey,Fin,Fantastic,Shell), I would like to provide a filter e.g. (B,F) and have the result of the above values (Bob,Bin,Fin,Fantastic)

Comment: Could you please describe an example scenario (what are the items in the list, what are your filtering criteria and the expected result)? It's hard to understand the problem now. As a first guess, I would say you should use `Any` instead of `All`.

Comment: @MM: sry I did not see your *answer* (Avoid answering to questions in comment)

Comment: @MártonMolnár was totally correct, its working fine. I cant accept it since its not an answer:(

Comment: @sac1 It wasn't an answer, just a request for clarification and a wild guess. It _turned out_ to be the correct answer, which I should have posted as an answer (as per [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291922/should-i-post-my-correctly-guessed-comment-as-an-answer) meta question), but by the time I got online again, there were already a few, so it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `.All` means: it contains B and F too (and condition)

but you need `.Any` (or condition)

```
public static bool ContainsAll(this string source, params string[] values)
{
    return values.Any(x => source.Contains(x));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's optimal, but it works:

```
string[] collection = new string[] {"Bob", "Bin", "Grey", "Fin", "Fantastic", "Shell" };
string filter = "B,F"; // TextBoxValue
string[] filterStrings = filter.Split(',');
string results = string.Join(",", collection.Where(c => filterStrings.Any(f => c.Contains(f))));
```

You can adjust it to your needs.